# proof environment

Tags: syntax

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\textit{Induktionsanfang:} $\Gamma (1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt=1=0!$\\
\hspace{1cm}\\
\textit{Induktionsschritt:} \qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
\hspace{-0.7cm}\Gamma (n+1)&=n\Gamma (n) \hspace{1.6cm} (2.85)\\
&=n\cdot (n-1)! \qquad (\textit{Induktionsvoraussetzung})\\
&=n!
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Why does it put the qed box at the wrong place? I want it at the very last line. 
Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the alignment to the top (I mean the `[t]` option of aligned environment -- try another alignment to see the difference).

But this problem can be solevd with `\qedhere` command (an `\hspace` command before `\qedhere` should work too if you need some space)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\textit{Induktionsanfang:} $\Gamma (1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt=1=0!$\\
\\ %\hspace before this line break does nothing
\textit{Induktionsschritt:} \qquad
\(
\begin{aligned}[t]
\hspace{-0.7cm}\Gamma (n+1)&=n\Gamma (n) \hspace{1.6cm}(2.85)\\
&=n\cdot (n-1)! \qquad (\textit{Induktionsvoraussetzung})\\
&=n!\qedhere
\end{aligned}\)
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\textit{Induktionsanfang:} $\Gamma (1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt=1=0!$\\
\hspace{1cm}\\
\textit{Induktionsschritt:} \qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
\hspace{-0.7cm}\Gamma (n+1)&=n\Gamma (n) \hspace{1.6cm} (2.85)\\
&=n\cdot (n-1)! \qquad (\textit{Induktionsvoraussetzung})\\
&=n! 
\end{aligned}$ \\[-\baselineskip] \qedhere
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using explicit widths, it's better to use more alignment points with `alignedat`.

I'd also avoid heavy usage of italics.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Induktionsanfang:\quad $\displaystyle\Gamma (1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\,dt=1=0!$

\medskip

\noindent
Induktionsschritt:\quad
$\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
  \Gamma(n+1) &= n\Gamma(n)    &\qquad& \text{(2.85)} \\
              &= n\cdot (n-1)! &&       \text{(Induktionsvoraussetzung)} \\
              &= n!            &&
\end{alignedat}$\\*[-\baselineskip]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]